# How to initialise Facebook SDK in iOS 14(SwiftUI) Widget Extension?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, facebook-ios-sdk

How do I initialisation Facebook SDK in iOS 14(SwiftUI) widget extension? Where do I need to call below method?

```
ApplicationDelegate.shared.application( application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

My end goal is to call GraphRequest from my widget. And according to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#step-3--connect-the-app-delegate), to call graph request we need to initialise Facebook SDK first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution at HackingWithSwift
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app

It uses a AppDelegate in the main view

Answer (score 0):

only a minor note:
If you are writing app from scratch and think You will need Appdelegate logic, you can select at start:

[image]

where You get:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```